# how to reference artifact version from dependencyManagement in the maven pom

Tags: maven-3

I have the following maven pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc.def.ghi</groupId>
<artifactId>core-with-releases</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<properties>
<yum-repo>/var/www/html/core-repo</yum-repo>
</properties>
<organization>
<name>ABC DEF GHI</name>
</organization>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <type>rpm</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
<plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>create-directory</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <executable>mkdir</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>${yum-repo}${dependencies["com.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:core"].version}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
 </project>
```

I execute from command line

mvn clean process-resources

As a result, I want directory to be created with the name ending with the version of the artifact from the dependencyManagement element which is 1.1.3

Can somebody help with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use properties for such purposes:

```
<properties>
  <yum-repo>/var/www/html/core-repo</yum-repo>
  <dep.groupId>com.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd</dep.groupId>
  <dep.artifactId>core</dep.artifactId>
  <dep.version>1.1.3</dep.version>
</properties>
<organization>
<name>ABC DEF GHI</name>
</organization>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>${dep.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${dep.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${dep.version}</version>
    <type>rpm</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
  ...
        <configuration>
          <executable>mkdir</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>${yum-repo}${dep.version}</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  ...
```

You should be aware of that by defining a dependency in *dependencyManagement* the dependency will *not* be bound as dependency to your current project.

Comment: I agree with this solution.   It should be noted that if we are talking about a Spring Boot project, Spring Boot provides a way to inject a bean with properties from the POM file.